# Tengo una duda mi programa de listas circulares me inserta el primer nodo pero al momento de insertar otro me da error me podria ayudar a mejorarlo

Tags: java, eclipse, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Método para insertar un nodo en una lista me da error al momento de insertar otro nodo

Aquí el código donde tengo problemas:

```
public void insertar(int dato)
 {
  if(cabecera == null)
  {
   cabecera = new Nodo(dato);
  }
  else{

   cabecera.setant(new Nodo(cabecera.getant(),dato,cabecera)); 
   cabecera.getant().getant().setsig(cabecera.getant());
  }
 }
```

Comment: Por favor selecciona la opción **editar** que se encuentra al pie del texto de la pregunta. Allí podrás agregar más información a tu pregunta. En esta ocasión lo haré yo, si deseas agregar más información te pido que lo hagas :)

Comment: ¿Qué clase de error te arroja ese código? Por favor brinda más información al respecto. Considera que no tenemos una bola mágica de cristal para ver lo que sucede en tu equipo ni en tu cabeza cuando revisas esto, solo tenemos como información el código que nos provees. Brinda todo lo necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: Ok, por favor **edita** la pregunta y brinda el contenido del stacktrace. No te preocupes si es muy largo. Y hazlo como texto, no como imagen por favor.

Answer (score 1):

cabecera.getant().getant() te devuelve **NullPointerException** porque el primer getant() te retorna null.

```
public void insertar(int dato) {
    if (this.cabecera == null) {
        this.cabecera = new Nodo(dato);
        this.fin = this.cabecera;
    } else {
        Nodo nuevoNodo = new Nodo(dato);
        nuevoNodo.setSig(this.cabecera);
        this.fin.setSig(nuevoNodo);
        this.fin = nuevoNodo;
    }
}
```

Te sugiero que en tu clase de lista circular mantengas un puntero que te permita guardar cual fue el ultimo nodo agregado. Esto te ayuda a mejorar los tiempos de inserción.